# Is it possible to deploy multiple shiny apps to one server using NGINX?

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, shiny-server

Ideally if I have two applications I would like one server to be able to serve both.

Currently my config file supports one shiny application deployed at port 3838.

Is it possible to have another instance of shiny server running at another port, so that my one server can host two different applications?

If so, what would the config file look like if I were trying to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you do not want another server but another application on the same server.

Do not confuse **two applications** listening on different ports with **one server with two applications** listening on just one port, because usually there should be just ONE server, as you said, listening on port 3838 that, depending on the URL, will provide one application or another.

If you already have a `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` file, you should just add directives in order for the server to send requests to one application instead of the other one.

You should edit that file with these rules:

```
server {
  ...
  # When accessing yourServer:3838/specialApp1
  location /specialApp1 {
    # Nginx will send the request to this application
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/myApp
  }
  
  # When accessing yourServer:3838/specialApp2
  location /specialApp2 {
    # Nginx will send the request to this application
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/myApp2
  }
...
}
```

Hope it helps! If not, please post your `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` file!

Answer (score 2):

Do you need separate instances of your server, or do you need to serve two applications?

On first installation of Shiny Server, the first page tells you how to add multiple applications. You should be able to simply place them in separate folders, e.g. `/srv/shiny-server/app1` and `../app2`.

This is also described in the [Configuration Reference](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#server-management), at **2.2.2 Location**

```
server {
  ...
  # Define the location '/specialApp'
  location /specialApp {
    # Run this location in 'app_dir' mode, which will host a single Shiny
    # Application available at '/srv/shiny-server/myApp'
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/myApp
  }
  
  # Define the location '/otherApps'
  location /otherApps {
    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server/apps'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server/apps;
  }
...
}
```